# Python: ThreadPoolExecutor Output Issue

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

I'm having an issue with my code that I can't seem to figure out. I have tried solutions from similar posts online but was not able to solve my problem.

My problem is that when I try to run the following code with `ThreadPoolExecutor`, I can't seem to get the output that the func returns from my executor.  Also I am using `executor.map()` because I need the results in the order of my submission.

```
def func(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i):
    do work...
    output = dict(data)
    print(output)
    return(output)

dfdata = {'b': [1, 2], 'h': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = dfdata)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = {executor.map(func(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)) for b, h in zip(df['b'], df['h'])}
    for result in results:
        print(result)
        print(list(result))
        print(dict(result))
```

I get the following output:

Output from the print function in func:

```
{Data set 1}
{Data set 1}
```

Output from the first print function in executor:

```
<generator object Executor.map.<locals>.result_iterator at 0x0E557B18>
<generator object Executor.map.<locals>.result_iterator at 0x0E557B50>
```

Output from the second print function in executor: empty list

```
[]
[]
```

Output from the third print function in executor: empty set

```
{}
{}
```

I am essentially looking to get the data from the `print(result)`.  I know that the executor is properly running my function because it prints the data on the first print call.  Not sure what I'm missing here?

Comment: The code as presented won't work - you reference a lot of variables that have no value and you only pass a single thing to `map` (namely the result of a call to `func`), you probably want to call with just `func` and an iterable which contains the various combinations of arguments to `func`, but I think the place to start is the documentation on `.map()`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Thank you for your assistance on this Grismar... there were multiple issues in my code but the main one was the improper use of the map function.  I have fixed it and it works now.

Comment: Can you please post the solution? @hotjoker I am facing kind of the same issue.

Comment: just convert your generator class to list and then print, it will work